# Magento base url changed in database, not reflecting on front end

Tags: magento

I have a problem with my magento site. I changed the secure and unsecure base url in the core_config_data table to a new value and when I go to the site the new value is not used. Its like its not even paying attention to what the database says.

I cleared the cache too. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you changed it in correct DB?

Comment: and your local.xml points to that db?

Comment: @DanielWhite If I was in your position: 1 ) Will check what is the DB name used in local.xml, because sometimes I setup 2 different version of one shop on the server or my local machine. 2 ) I will do search for "web/unsecure/base_url" and "web/secure/base_url" in core_config_data, because sometimes if you have more than one store or website in your Magento installation, you many have more than 2 records for "web/unsecure/base_url" and "web/secure/base_url".

Comment: How did you clear cache? Are you sure cache is writing under ./var - not under your server tmp dir?

Comment: Is your website still accessible from web?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution is to rename /app/etc/local.xml to /app/etc/local.xml.old and restart the installation process.

My problem was that I typed the wrong base url for javascript (forgot to add the /js/ at the end), so javascript did not work on the frontend or backend. After changing the base js url and clearing the cache, still no js. Only after renaming local.xml and going through the installation process did the correct js url (with the /js/) kick in.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ever having problems manually changing the core_config_data table to represent the proper URLs, especially when working locally, rename /app/etc/local.xml to local.xmlcopy (or wtv).

This has always been my failsafe; I always do it manually, but when all else fails, this almost always works.

Go through the installation process (Do not worry: It will not delete your data; it'll know the tables are created).

That's it. Go to the front end, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case was memcache prefix, the same that another store in the same server.